# react scripts build failed to compile

Tags: reactjs, heroku

When deploying my create-react-app with heroku, My react scripts build fails, and it can not find some file.
But everything works just fine locally.

steps i did when deploying the app:
1) heroku create nameoftheApp --buildpack https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack.git.
2) run git push heroku master.
Thats all i did. Then I got the same error stating I have to Add node version. So I added the version. And this is what I got after adding the version and trying to redeploy again.
It might be stupid but I'm pretty new to Heroku (deploying apps in general) so im sorry about that.

```
remote:        Creating an optimized production build...
remote:        Failed to compile.
remote:
remote:        ./src/components/pages/Home.js
remote:        Cannot find file '../home-menu/MenuMain' in './src/components/pages'.
remote:
remote:
remote: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
remote: npm ERR! errno 1
remote: npm ERR! royal@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
remote: npm ERR! Exit status 1
remote: npm ERR!
remote: npm ERR! Failed at the royal@0.1.0 build script.
remote: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Comment: Have you tried deploying to Heroku the standard CRA? The one just after you do the local "npm install"?

Comment: You mean at the beggining when I just started the project ? I only tried to deploy once finished the app, and the only 2 steps i did are the ones i mentioned, i didnt add anything to the package.json file or anywhere, thats so frustrating :D

Comment: Yes, the one just after you start the project. The reason I asked is because it seems the build is not finding a file and an import is failing.

Comment: Sometimes casing issues cause import fails. For example, Windows is able to import something like ```Menumain.js``` but on linux ```MenuMain.js``` it would fail. Not exactly that but you get the point. But that's just a guess, of course.

Comment: Oh yeah it makes sens, and I didnt do that actually, I only did it at the end... i guess its not good practice. I m gonna try to put it lowercase then, thank you